# SELECT vs FindFirst VBA Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, select

Trying get a quick answer since research yielded no results and I'm not sure how to test the speeds of this.  Scenario is I have a table with 20 fields and 26000 rows give or take.  There is a form that is bound to some fields of that table where the table will populate the fields.  So I type in a part and it will populate the description, average cost, and product code.

Now my question:  Should I use a `SELECT` statement after I type in the part and use that statement to populate the form fields each time I check on a part?  So a recordset will be created, set, then set to nothing each time.  Or should I run a `SELECT` statement for all the fields I will need from the table, set a recordset with those 26000 rows, then use `.FindFirst` on that recordset each time?  Which is quicker or which is correct?

I may be going about this completely wrong too, but I'm just trying to learn as I go.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about the time consuming ? I think 26000 records is not a big number but I can't tell which one is faster. However , 2 methods that you are talking about are different . The first one give you a set of recordset while the 2nd with .FindFirst only give you back 1 record . I don't get what you want to do here , so if you can elaborate more that would be helpful.

Comment: I was just curious what the proper procedure for something like this would be.  `SELECET` all rows and store those for quick access with a `.FindFirst`, or just use `SELECT` on a case by case basis.  I want to understand what is considered "proper procedure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the first one, the simple one:  A simple `SELECT` statement that runs each time.

The other method might be good for a table ten times larger (maybe), and for taking care of more complicated procedures; the purpose and the table you have described seems fine for managing in a simple way.

If it seems slow in operation, before trying a different recordset approach, just optimize the table by making sure the fields are properly indexed.